Accessing multiple constant props in dart
I am working on a design system that allows us to have a strict shade of each colors. So I can do TColors.red.red1. This approach won't work and I don't know why. Since this won't work out, what is the other way out to acheive same semantics of accessing my colors as Widget(style: TextStyle(color: TColor.red.red1))
abstract TColors {
   static const red = _MyRedColors();
}

class _MyRedColors {
   const _MyRedColors();

   final red1 = const Color(SomeRedColor);
}


Assigning colors as TColors.red.red1 is not possible in flutter. If you want to use different shades of the same color, you can choose those different shades using colorpicker or if you use VS code then just click on that color, different shades you can choose by just moving cursor. If you want to distinguish this different shades you can use them as static const red1 = Color(0xFFFF0000); another one static const red2 = Color(0xFFCC0000);, as such you add shades of your choice.
